# pyspark create a structType with conditions in a dateframe

Tags: pyspark

I have this dataframe

```
Item value
A      1
B      1
C      2
D      2
```

I want to get this

```
Item    value
{A,B}      1
{C,D}      2
```

Something like  groupby  'value' and  combine 'item
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DF:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('A', 1)
    ,('B', 1)
    ,('C', 2)
    ,('D', 2)
  ]
  ,['Item', 'value']
)
```

Steps are:

- create a dummy matrix
- apply a lambda function
- map the list returned by the lambda function to the column names list

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def map_func(list):
  z = []
  for index, elem in enumerate(list):
      if elem == 1:
        z.append(cols[index])
  return z

df = df.groupBy("value").pivot("Item").agg(F.lit(1)).fillna(0)
cols = df.columns[1:]

map_func_lamb = F.udf(lambda row: map_func(row))
df = df.withColumn("list", map_func_lamb(F.struct([df[x] for x in df.columns[1:]])))\
        .select(F.col("list").alias("Item"), "value")

df.show()

+------+-----+
|  Item|value|
+------+-----+
|[A, B]|    1|
|[C, D]|    2|
+------+-----+
```

Not sure if you really want a dic as a result or a list is fine, but I don't see much difference at this point

Comment: { } is spark struct type not dictionary.